# Differentiate $\sum_{ij}[\sum_{k}\log \frac{W_{ik}H_{kj}}{\alpha} + \sum_{k}W_{ik}H_{kj}] + \sum_{kj}[\frac{\beta}{2} \vert H_{kj} \vert^{2}] = 0$

Tags: matrices, proof-verification, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I would like to differentiate the following equation wrt. matrix $H_{kj}$ equal to $0$:

\begin{align}
D(W, H) = \sum_{ij}[\sum_{k}\log \frac{W_{ik}H_{kj}}{\alpha} + \sum_{k}W_{ik}H_{kj}] + \sum_{kj}[\frac{\beta}{2} \vert H_{kj} \vert^{2}]
\end{align}

where $W_{ik}$ and $H_{kj}$ are positive matrix with dimension $i*k$ and $k*j$, respectively. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constant.

Since $H_{kj}$ is positive, $\vert H_{kj}\vert = H_{kj}$:

\begin{align}
0 &= \frac{\partial}{\partial H_{kj}}[\sum_{ij}[\sum_{k}\log \frac{W_{ik}H_{kj}}{\alpha} + \sum_{k}W_{ik}H_{kj}] + \sum_{kj}[\frac{\beta}{2} H_{kj} ^{2}]]\\
&= \sum_{ij}[\sum_{k}\frac{\alpha}{W_{ik}H_{kj}} . \frac{W_{ik}}{\alpha} + \sum_{k}W_{ik}] + \sum_{kj}\beta H_{kj}\\
&= \sum_{kj}\frac{1}{H_{kj}}  + \sum_{ik}W_{ik} + \sum_{kj}\beta H_{kj}\\
\end{align}

For the fixed $k, j$:
\begin{align}
0 &= \frac{1}{H_{kj}}  + \sum_{i}W_{ik} + \beta H_{kj}\\
\end{align}

Multiply both sides of equation with $\frac{H_{kj}}{\beta}$:

\begin{align}
0 &= (\frac{1}{H_{kj}}.\frac{H_{kj}}{\beta}) + ( \sum_{i}W_{ik}.\frac{H_{kj}}{\beta}) + (\beta H_{kj}.\frac{H_{kj}}{\beta})\\
0&= \frac{1}{\beta} + \frac{ (\sum_{i}W_{ik})H_{kj}}{\beta} + H^{2}_{kj}\\
0 &= (H_{kj} + \frac{ \sum_{i}W_{ik}}{2\beta})^{2} - \frac{ (\sum_{i}W_{ik})^{2}}{4\beta^{2}} + \frac{1}{\beta}\\
\end{align}
Rearrange:
\begin{align}
(H_{kj} + \frac{ \sum_{i}W_{ik}}{2\beta})^{2}&= \frac{ (\sum_{i}W_{ik})^{2}}{4\beta^{2}} - \frac{1}{\beta}\\
\end{align}
Take square root both sides:
\begin{align}
H_{kj} + \frac{ \sum_{i}W_{ik}}{2\beta} &= \sqrt {\frac{(\sum_{i}W_{ik})^{2}}{4\beta^{2}} - \frac{1}{\beta}}\\
H_{kj} &= \sqrt {\frac{(\sum_{i}W_{ik})^{2}}{4\beta^{2}} - \frac{1}{\beta}} - \frac{\sum_{i}W_{ik}}{2\beta}\\
\end{align}

I wonder if this is correct? Since the equation has matrices, I am not sure for multiplying/dividing them together.

Comment: The terms in your equation have incompatible dimensions. The first two terms have the dimensions of the matrix product ($WH$) but the third term is unclear. It's meant to be either a scalar ($\|H\|^2$) or the element-wise square of a matrix ($H\odot H$). In either case, its dimensions are incompatible with the previous terms.

Comment: @greg Thanks so much for explanation. I edited my question. Sorry for missing many important points previously. If something is still wrong, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function can be written in matrix notation as 
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= {\mathbf 1}:\Big(WH+\log(WH)\Big) + \tfrac{\beta}{2}H:H \cr
}$$
where a colon denotes the trace/Frobenius product, i.e. $\,A\!:\!B={\rm tr}(A^TB),\,$
the matrix ${\mathbf 1}$ has the same shape as $WH$, and the $\log()$ function is applied element-wise.

The differential and gradient of this function is
$$\eqalign{
d\phi
  &= {\mathbf 1}:\Big(W\,dH+\frac{W\,dH}{WH}\Big) + \beta H:dH \cr
  &= \Big(W^T\Big(\frac{{\mathbf 1}+WH}{WH}\Big) + \beta H\Big):dH \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial H}
  &= W^T\Big(\frac{{\mathbf 1}+WH}{WH}\Big) + \beta H \cr
}$$
Now set the gradient to zero and solve for $H$ iteratively
$$\eqalign{
  H_+ &= -\beta^{-1}W^T\Big(\frac{{\mathbf 1}+WH}{WH}\Big) \cr
}$$
where the notation $\big(\frac{1}{WH}\big)$ represents element-wise division.

Comment: what cyclic rule did you apply to the first part of the differential? Say $B = W$, $C = \Big(I + \frac{W}{WH}\Big)$ such that  $d\phi = {\mathbf 1} \ : B \ C \ dH = B^T \  {\mathbf 1} \ C^T : dH$, is it? If yes, then there is a mismatch, right? or am I mixing up with the rules (quite high likelihood)?

Comment: May I ask if $log(WH)$ has a coefficient matrix, $\pi_{ijk}$, how can I write $\sum_{k} \pi_{ijk} log(W_{ik}H_{kj}) $ in matrix notation here? Since $\pi_{ijk}$ must be multiplied into $log(W_{ik}H_{kj})$ before sum of $k$ dimension, is it wrong to write $\pi log(WH)$?

Comment: Sorry for another question but why $H$ in the term $(\frac{1+WH}{WH})$ can remain and only $H$ in $\beta H$ is used to solve for $H_{+}$?

Comment: I just realized that to do an iterative update, $H$ should be at both LHS and RHS. Is this the right answer for why only $\beta H$ is used to be $H+$ on LHS (but not $WH$, to have $H$ on RHS) in the previous question? If yes, I still wonder how to choose which one will become $H+$ (on LHS), which one remain as $H$ (on RHS)? Is there any rules for this? Or any $H$ can be $H+$ but it should make the update on RHS as simple as possible?